# Ordering binary search trees

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

When trying to order a set of numbers into a binary search tree, is there always exactly one way to order them so the tree has the shortest height, in other words most efficient?

Comment: Is this an ordering of the elements of the tree itself, or of the set of numbers being inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set of numbers can be converted to a BST by taking one element as the root of the tree and arranging all other numbers around it.  I could see the following situation contradicting this theory:

Picking one root leads to a tree of height `h`, with the left subtree being 'taller' than the right subtree.
Picking another root leads to a different tree, also of height `h`, with the right subtree being 'taller' than the left subtree.

Another simple example involves swapping the order of insertion of two consecutive elements that are not directly related, and thus do not affect each other's position in the tree.

## Disproof by counter-example.

Let the set `S = {0, 1, 2, 3}`.
Insert the elements into a binary search tree in the following order: `1, 0, 2, 3`

```
  1
 / \
0   2
     \
      3
```

Insert the elements into a binary search tree in the following order: `1, 2, 0, 3`

```
  1
 / \
0   2
     \
      3
```

Because these two trees have different orders of insertion, and yet both have minimum height, the statement that there is only one order of insertion that provides a binary search tree of minimum height is false.

If the actual ordering of elements on the tree is what you're concerned about, insert the elements of the set in the following order: `2, 1, 0, 3`

```
    2
   / \
  1   3
 /
0
```

Again, this tree has the same height as the previous trees, thus showing that a different ordering of items in the tree can also produce a tree of minimum height.

---

(An aside)

You can always build a minimum height tree by first sorting the elements of the set, then continually subdividing the sorted set to ensure balance and complete filling of each row.

- Take the median element of the set.  In the case of an even number of elements, take the larger of the two 'middle' elements.  This will become the root of the tree.
- Take all the elements below the median.  This will become the left subtree of the root.
- Take all the elements above the median.  This will become the right subtree of the root.
- Recursively create the left and right subtrees from these sets.

This should ensure that you have a complete binary tree, which will always be of minimum height.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. But, is there only ONE unique ordering of the binary tree with minimum height?

Comment: This might be an issue of definition.  Intuitively, I would say absolutely not, but I don't have the time to post a full proof right now.

Comment: Suffice to say, the example I gave above (pick one root, then pick another root) is just one way in which this 'different ordering' could occur, and could easily be verified with a single example, at which point it would be proof by contradiction that, for some binary tree, there is more than one insertion order for which that tree can constructed with minimum height.

Comment: Went ahead and added a counterproof anyway.